# XOrg slow boot time

Tags: debian, x11, nvidia, startup

I have a Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 system with GNOME. It takes up to a minute to boot. I have two screens connected to a NVidia GTX 970.

```
[     7.660] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): connected
[     7.660] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.660] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.678] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[     7.678] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[     7.678] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.678] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): connected
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[     7.708] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    30.155] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): connected
[    30.155] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    30.155] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    30.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    30.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    30.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    30.173] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): connected
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    30.204] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.080] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): connected
[    61.080] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.080] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.098] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    61.098] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    61.098] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.098] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): connected
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.128] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.171] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1366+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[    61.217] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[    61.700] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): connected
[    61.700] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 1950w (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.700] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.717] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    61.717] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    61.717] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.717] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): connected
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): Internal TMDS
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung S22B350 (DFP-1): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    61.747] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
`
```

You can see in the above snippet of /var/log/Xorg.0.log that the monitors are checked several times, and it causes huge jumps in startup time.

The problem persists with both an empty xorg.conf and an auto-generated xorg.conf by nvidia-xconfig.

Does anybody have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Use the nouveau driver or report the bug to nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but a guess:

The `NVIDIA` driver is looking for the EDID information of the monitor, the monitor is not responding because it's either an old monitor, the cable is broken etc., and the whole thing only continues after a timeout when the driver finally decides it won't get an answer.

There are `xorg.conf` options to suppress getting EDID information, though I am not sure if they are available for the `NVIDIA` driver.